# Get sub-tasks for a given task in Project Online CSOM

Tags: csom, project-server, project-online

I m trying to get all tasks, which have given task as a parent using CSOM:

```
projContext.Load(tasks, c => c.Where(t => t.Parent.Id == parentId));
```

Here `projContext` is a valid context and `parentId` is the Id of a valid task.

I get error:

> [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException] {"Unknown Error"}       at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream
>   responseStream)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder
>   sb)    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQuery()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.ExecuteQuery()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()

What is wrong? How to do it correctly? Thank you.

Comment: try this: projContext.Load(tasks, c => c.Where(t => t.Parent != null && t.Parent.Id == parentId));

Comment: @Damjan Tomic, thank you VERY much for this valuable advise. It worked! Silly enough, I despaired to figure out so simple thing in several hours. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the query to this: `projContext.Load(tasks, c => c.Where(t => t.Parent != null && t.Parent.Id == parentId));`